# Выполняет два условие (это бот в вк)

Tags: python, вконтакте, if

```
proverka="no"
nomer="no"
bal="58744585"
                elif "вывести" in response:
                    a=list(response)
                    for vivod in range(8):
                        a.pop(0)
                    a="".join(a)
                    file=open(str(event.obj.peer_id)+".txt","r")
                    bal=file.read()
                    file.close()
                    bal=int(bal)
                    a=int(a)
                    if a < 10000000:
                        send_message(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id,message="от 10 рублей")
                    else:
                        if bal < a:
                            send_message(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id,message="Недостаточно DRC для покупки")
                        else:
                            file=open("nomer."+str(event.obj.peer_id)+".txt","r")
                            nomer=file.read()
                            file.close()
                            nomer=str(nomer)
                            if nomer in proverka:
                                print(proverka)
                                print(nomer)
                                send_message(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id,message="введите свои данные через номер (номер) (банк), и принимается Юмани, киви и операторы связи")
                            else:
                                print(proverka)
                                print(nomer)
                        a=int(a)
                        bal=bal-a
                        bal=str(bal)
                        file=open(str(event.obj.peer_id)+".txt","w")
                        file.write(bal)
                        file.close()
                        send_message(peer_id=admin_id, message=str(a)+" сумма https://vk.com/id"+str(event.obj.peer_id)+" номер "+nomer)
                        send_message(peer_id = event.obj.peer_id, message="угу вывод создан")
```

Ввод: вывести 58744585

Ответ: введите свои данные через номер (номер) (банк), и принимается Юмани, киви и операторы связи

Ответ: 58744585 сумма https://vk.com/id607934046 номер no

Ответ: угу вывод создан

В консоли:

```
no
no
```

Comment: Запустите отладку и по шагам посмотрите что откуда считывается или не считывается.

Comment: Очень непонятно, чего вы именно хотите и что именно в вашем коде не так. В первую очередь, добавьте [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](/help/mcve), что бы мы могли повторить вашу ошибку. И подскажите: какую библиотеку вы используете?